# Lookup Tables in Case List Calculation

Tags: commcare

Is it possible to reference a lookup table in a case list calculation in CommCare?

I think I know the syntax that I would need to use, but CommCare doesn't have access to the right instance at that point.  Is there a way I can access that instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding was that if you reference a fixture inside a calculate using `instance('item-list:my_table')/my_table_list/my_table` (where `my_table` is the name of your lookup table), that instance will be detected and included automatically. If that doesn't work would you mind editing your question to include the expression you're using?

EDIT: I had originally said to include `instance('item-list')` which was incorrect. The above should allow the app to build, and if `my_table` exists and is assigned to the user then it should work correctly.